# Setting TaskbarItemInfo via WPF Style or Trigger

Tags: wpf, windows-7, dependency-properties

WPF 4 includes a "TaskbarItemInfo" Freezable class that adds an attached property to a Window that allows various Windows 7 taskbar items to be changed.

In particular, I'm trying to set progress information on the tasbar icon for the Window. I'd like to use a DataTrigger to do this, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried using a simple style setter, but that doesn't work either - only direct property assignment or direct property bindings will work.

For example:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState" Value="Indeterminate" />
    </Style>
</Window.Style>

<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo />
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

It appears as though the attached property is not being set via the style. Is my syntax for setting attached properties via styles incorrect, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

`TaskbarItemInfo` doesn't inherit from `FrameworkElement` so there is no `Style` property for you to set in the `DataTrigger`.

Why don't you bind your `TaskbarItemInfo`'s `ProgressState` to the property you were thinking of using in your `DataTrigger` and then use a `ValueConverter` to convert that to the relevant `TaskbarItemProgressState`.

```xaml
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo ProgressState="{Binding YourProperty, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ProgressStateConverter}}" />
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

Then a simple converter can return whichever `TaskbarItemProgressState` applies to your trigger property.

Comment: Would this state update with changes to the property?